# Joining a subquery with a join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery, correlated-subquery

Attempting to apply a subquery to table for the purpose of being able to group it.

**Main Query**

```
 SELECT soitem.fsono, fpartno, soitem.fcfromno, finumber
 FROM soitem 
 INNER JOIN somast on soitem.fsono = somast.fsono  
 WHERE somast.fsono='034313'  
 ORDER by soitem.fsono, soitem.finumber
```

**Subquery**

```
SELECT min(sq.finumber), sq.fcfromno 
FROM soitem sq 
WHERE sq.fsono='034313' 
GROUP BY sq.fcfromno
```

**[image: I want to use the <code>min_finumber</code> to further group my data set. This should appear as three rows]**

I want to use the `min_finumber` to further group my data set. This should appear as three rows. I used my original question as way to incorporate the subquery into my overall code. My main goal is being able to successfully group the `min_number`

```
SELECT somast.fsono, 
somast.fcustno, 
somast.fcontact, 
somast.fcustpono, 
somast.fshipvia, 
somast.forderdate, 
somast.fduedate,
 soship.fccompany, 
 soship.fcphone, 
  REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), soship.fmstreet), CHAR(13), '|'), CHAR(10), ' ') AS Street,
soship.fccity,
 soship.fcstate, 
 soship.fczip,
 CAST(somast.fackmemo as CHAR(35)) as ShipCode, 
 somast.fordername,
  somast.fcusrchr2,
somast.fcusrchr3,
somast.fcusrchr1, 
somast.festimator, 
soitem.fcfromno, 
 soitem.fcfromtype,
  CASE WHEN soitem.fcfromtype <> 'IFPKIT' THEN soitem.fpartno ELSE soitem.fcfromno END AS Item, 
 CASE WHEN soitem.fcfromtype <> 'IFPKIT' THEN soitem.fquantity ELSE soitem.fquantity / soitem.fquoteqty END AS Qty, 
CASE WHEN soitem.fcfromtype <> 'IFPKIT' 
THEN CAST(soitem.fdesc as CHAR(35))
ELSE 'Store Set (Phantom)' END as Descr

FROM soitem INNER JOIN
 somast ON soitem.fsono = somast.fsono LEFT OUTER JOIN
 soship ON somast.fsono = soship.fcsono AND soship.fcenumber = ''

WHERE   
(somast.fstatus <> 'Cancelled') AND (somast.fsocoord = 'IFP' OR
 somast.fsocoord = '711')
 Group By REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), soship.fmstreet), CHAR(13), '|'), CHAR(10), ' '),
 CAST(somast.fackmemo as CHAR(35)),
 somast.fsono,
somast.fcustno,
fcontact,
fcustpono,
fshipvia,
forderdate,
somast.fduedate,

CASE WHEN soitem.fcfromtype<>'IFPKIT' 
THEN soitem.fpartno 
ELSE soitem.fcfromno END,

CASE WHEN soitem.fcfromtype<>'IFPKIT' 
THEN soitem.fquantity 
ELSE soitem.fquantity/soitem.fquoteqty END,

CASE WHEN soitem.fcfromtype <> 'IFPKIT' 
THEN CAST(soitem.fdesc as CHAR(35))
ELSE 'Store Set (Phantom)' END,

soship.fccity, 
soship.fcstate, 
soship.fczip,
fordername, 
fcusrchr2, 
fcusrchr3,
 fcusrchr1, 
festimator,
soitem.fcfromno, 
soitem.fcfromtype,
 soship.fccompany,
  soship.fcphone

ORDER BY somast.forderdate, somast.fsono, soitem.fcfromno
```

Comment: Please explain what "apply a subquery to a table" means.  Sample data and desired results help.

Comment: So it looks like you're trying to find the both the current row's `finumber` and the minimum `finumber` in the `soitem` table, correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I've been trying to join them using fsono+finumber.

Comment: Do you want the minimum `finumber` and `fcfrom` even if there is no `soitem` match to the `somast` table or the minimums for just matched records?

Comment: And are `fpartno` and `finumber` in the `SELECT coming from the `soitem` table or the `somast` table?

Comment: I want to say just matched records because there should always be a matching item.

Comment: `fpartno` and `finumber`  come from `soitem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using a join or subquery. I was able to get the results I needed by adding `min(finumber)` as min_fin to the `SELECT`and `ORDER BY`

```
select soitem.fsono, 
somast.fcustno, 
somast.fcontact, 
somast.fcustpono, 
somast.fshipvia, 
somast.forderdate, 
somast.fduedate,
 soship.fccompany, 
 soship.fcphone, 
REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), soship.fmstreet), CHAR(13), '|'), CHAR(10), ' ') AS Street,
soship.fccity,
 soship.fcstate, 
 soship.fczip,
CAST(somast.fackmemo as CHAR(35)) as ShipCode,
CASE WHEN soitem.fcfromtype <> 'IFPKIT' THEN soitem.fpartno ELSE soitem.fcfromno END AS Item, 
CASE WHEN soitem.fcfromtype <> 'IFPKIT' THEN soitem.fquantity ELSE soitem.fquantity / soitem.fquoteqty END AS Qty, 
CASE WHEN soitem.fcfromtype <> 'IFPKIT' 
THEN CAST(soitem.fdesc as CHAR(35))
ELSE 'Store Set (Phantom)' END as Descr,
somast.fordername,
  somast.fcusrchr2,
somast.fcusrchr3,
somast.fcusrchr1, 
somast.festimator, 
soitem.fcfromno, 
soitem.fcfromtype, 

**min(finumber)as min_fin** 

from soitem INNER JOIN
 somast ON soitem.fsono = somast.fsono
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 soship ON somast.fsono = soship.fcsono AND soship.fcenumber = ''

  where soitem.fsono='034313' 

group by soitem.fsono, CASE WHEN soitem.fcfromtype <> 'IFPKIT' THEN soitem.fpartno ELSE soitem.fcfromno END, 
soitem.fcfromno, soitem.fcfromtype,
somast.fcustno, 
somast.fcontact, 
somast.fcustpono, 
somast.fshipvia, 
somast.forderdate, 
somast.fduedate,
 soship.fccompany, 
 soship.fcphone,
 REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), soship.fmstreet), CHAR(13), '|'), CHAR(10), ' '),
soship.fccity,
 soship.fcstate, 
 soship.fczip,
 CAST(somast.fackmemo as CHAR(35)),
 CASE WHEN soitem.fcfromtype <> 'IFPKIT' THEN soitem.fquantity ELSE soitem.fquantity / soitem.fquoteqty END , 
CASE WHEN soitem.fcfromtype <> 'IFPKIT' 
THEN CAST(soitem.fdesc as CHAR(35))
ELSE 'Store Set (Phantom)' END, 
 somast.fordername,
  somast.fcusrchr2,
somast.fcusrchr3,
somast.fcusrchr1, 
somast.festimator

order by soitem.fsono, **min_fin**;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using SQL Server 2008 R2, you have access to the window function you need. Try something like:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/83c59/1)

SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE soitem 
(
     fsono INT, 
     fpartno INT,
     soitem INT, 
     finumber INT, 
     fcfromno INT
);

INSERT INTO soitem (fsono, fpartno, soitem, finumber, fcfromno)
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2, 5, 1), 
       (2, 2, 2, 9, 2), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
       (3, 2, 2, 1, 9);

CREATE TABLE somast (fsono int) ;

INSERT INTO somast (fsono)
VALUES (1), (2);
```

Main query:

```
SELECT 
    soitem.fsono,
    soitem.fpartno,
    soitem.fcfromno,
    soitem.finumber,
    /* THE BELOW PART IS YOUR "JOIN" */
    MIN(soitem.finumber) OVER (PARTITION BY soitem.fsono, soitem.fcfromno) AS min_finumber
FROM 
    soitem 
INNER JOIN 
    somast ON soitem.fsono = somast.fsono  
WHERE 
    somast.fsono = '1'
ORDER BY
    soitem.fsono, soitem.finumber
```

[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/83c59/1/0):

```
| fsono | fpartno | fcfromno | finumber | min_finumber |
|-------|---------|----------|----------|--------------|
|     1 |       1 |        1 |        1 |            1 |
|     1 |       2 |        1 |        5 |            1 |
```

Your main query:

```
SELECT soitem.fsono, fpartno, soitem.fcfromno, finumber
FROM soitem 
INNER JOIN somast on soitem.fsono = somast.fsono  
WHERE somast.fsono='1'  
ORDER by soitem.fsono, soitem.finumber
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/83c59/1/1)**:

```
| fsono | fpartno | fcfromno | finumber |
|-------|---------|----------|----------|
|     1 |       1 |        1 |        1 |
|     1 |       2 |        1 |        5 |
```

**Your Subquery**:

```
SELECT min(sq.finumber), sq.fcfromno 
FROM soitem sq 
WHERE sq.fsono='1' 
GROUP BY sq.fcfromno
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/83c59/1/2)**:

```
|   | fcfromno |
|---|----------|
| 1 |        1 |
```

Comment: This gets the results that I need but I'm not able to GROUP BY `min_finumber`

Comment: `min_finumber` doesn't exist when the `GROUP BY` runs. Essentially, a SQL query logically process like this: `FROM > WHERE > GROUP BY > HAVING > SELECT > DISTINCT > ORDER BY > TOP`. If you need to `GROUP BY` `min_finumber`, then enclose the query in another subquery. What are you trying to do with the new `GROUP BY`? There may be a better way to get what you're ultimately after.

Comment: I want to be able to be to find the `min_finumber'  so I can group it because they're is duplicate data . I'm using a `Group By` on all of the fields in the `Select` statement.

Comment: What is being duplicated? You have multiple matches between `soitem` and `somast`? You may be able to filter your `JOIN` tighter so there aren't duplicates. If you can provide an example of sample data for both tables that is duplicating, I can adjust my query.

Comment: So how are you aggregating for your second `GROUP BY`? You want 3 rows, but those groups are made up of different `fpartno`. Can you provide a sample of your expected results and a description of why you expect those results? It seems like there's a step or a group missing somewhere to get the data that you need.

Comment: I'm posting the entire query that I'm using. This should give you a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve. I want to get them grouped by their lowest `min_finumber` is because currently they aren't in numeric order when a certain case statement is met. The data is being exported to excel that has to be compared line by line.

Comment: If you include `fpartno`, you can't further group them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179474/discussion-between-david-and-shawn).